# Configuracion base de datos maria db

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Actualmente manejo un website que mantiene unas 30 conexiones simultaneas continuas hasta allí esta bien, pero en `phpmyadmin` me han aparecido una serie de alertas desde la sección "estado actual", todas las variables de estado, en resumen son estas las alertas:

#### Aborted clients

3k

> La cantidad de conexiones que fueron abandonadas porque el cliente
>   murió sin cerrar la conexión apropiadamente.

#### Aborted connects

21.3 k

> Cantidad de intentos de conexión al servidor MySQL fallidos.

#### Created tmp disk tables

378 k

> El número de tablas temporales en el disco que fueron creados
>   automáticamente por el servidor mientras ejecuta las sentencias. Si
>   las tablas Created_tmp_disk_tables es grande, puede incrementar el
>   valor de tmp_table_size para hacer que las tablas temporales se basen
>   en memoria en lugar de basarse en disco.

#### Handler read rnd

13.6 G

> El número de solicitudes hechas para leer una fila basado en una
>   posición fija. Este es alto si usted está haciendo muchas consultas
>   que requieren el reordenamiento del resultado. Usted probablemente
>   tiene muchas consultas que requieren que MySQL escanee tablas enteras
>   o usted debe tener vínculos (joins) que no usan las claves de manera
>   apropiada.

#### Handler read rnd next

175.6 G

> El número de solicitudes hechas para leer la siguiente fila en el
>   archivo de datos. Este es alto si usted está haciendo muchos escaneos
>   de tablas. Generalmente, esto sugiere que sus tablas no están
>   indizadas apropiadamente o que sus consultas no están escritas para
>   tomar ventaja de los índices que tiene.

#### Innodb buffer pool reads

61.5 M

> El número de lecturas lógicas que InnoDB no pudo satisfacer la reserva
>   de búfers y donde fue necesario hacer lectura de página sencilla.

#### Innodb row lock time avg

1.1 k

> El tiempo promedio para adquirir un row lock, en milisegundos.

#### Innodb row lock time max

34.2 k

> El tiempo máximo para adquirir un row lock, en milisegundos.

#### Innodb row lock waits

2.1 k

> El número de veces que un row lock tuvo que esperarse.

#### Opened tables

1.2 k

> El número de tablas que han sido abiertas. Si el número de tablas abiertas es grande, su valor del cache de tabla probablemente es muy pequeño.

#### Select full join

12.1 k

> El número de vínculos (joins) que no usan índices. Si este valor no es
>   0, deberá revisar los índices de sus tablas cuidadosamente.

#### Slow queries

27.5 k

> El número de consultas que han tomado más segundos que los registrados
>   en long_query_time.Documentación

#### Sort merge passes

53.1 k

> El número de pasadas de combinación que el algoritmo organizar ha
>   debido hacer. Si este valor es grande, debe considerar incrementar el
>   valor de la varible de sistema sort_buffer_size.

#### Table locks waited

812

> El número de veces que un table lock no pudo adquirirse inmediatamente
>   y fue necesaria una espera. Si este valor es alto, y hay problemas de
>   rendimiento, primero deberá optimizar sus consultas, y luego, ya sea
>   partir sus tablas o usar replicación.

```
Tipo de servidor: MariaDB
Versión del servidor: 10.0.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - Ubuntu 16.04
Versión del protocolo: 10
```

Comment: ¿Y cual sería la pregunta?

Comment: Primeramente, quisiera saber donde se realiza la configuración de innodb que es el motor de almacenamiento que usamos, para hacer los ajustes que indican, ya que en my.cnf no logro entenderlo, y la documentacion es muy tecnica al momento de explicar.